# Given $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ irreducible. How many and which roots of $f$ are contained in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$?

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots, extension-field

It is a fact that struggle me for a while. When working with irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ it is natural to build the extension ${\mathbb{Q}[x]}/{(f)} $ in which "lives " one root of the polynomial. More precisely, $[x]$ is a root of the polynomial in this extension.

BUT

Take for example $f= x^3-2$ which roots are $ 2^{1/3} , \ w2^{1/3} , \ w^2 2^{1/3}$ where $w \in RPU(3)$. Doing the extension (the same as above) I build a field where $[x]$ is a root of $f$. Where are the other two roots? I don't think they are here, just for a matter of dimension as vector space over the field of rationals. I calculate the size of the splitting field of $f$ and have as a result 6. But my extension have dimension 3 over Q. So something is missing. Why? And if this reasoning is correct, given an irreducible polynomial $g$, which root(s) I found in this way?

Hope it is clear :), thanks in advance :)

Comment: At least one, and '*which*' has no sense in this setting, as *this root* can be taken into any other root by a field automorphism of a (perhaps bigger) field over which $f$ factors to linear components.

Comment: Yeah, I know but can we say something more about this quantity? Or we need more hypothesis?

Comment: Yeah my fault:(

Comment: Not a problem! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other two roots are in an extension field of the field you have found.

As to which root you find, unmask the question. There is no way, from an algebraic point of view, to distinguish among the roots of an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Ok, clear (forgot this fact :( ) so we can't say nothing more about quantity of roots in a given extension?

Comment: I'm trying to be more clear, let $f=x^3-2$, WITHOUT knowing explicitly the roots of the polynomial, is there a way to say that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f)$ isn't the splitting field for $f$?

Comment: For equations of degree 3 over the rationals, you can calculate the *discriminant*; if it is a square, then adjoining one root adjoins all three roots; if it's not a square, then you need to do a quadratic extension (by the square root of the discriminant) to get the other two roots. There are techniques for higher degrees, but it gets more complicated the higher the degree.

Comment: Is it generally so, that if $f$ has degree $3$ and a splitting field of degree $6$ over $\mathbb Q$, then adding one root adds only one and the other two comes with the second extension?

Comment: @String, of course. If adding one root adds a second, then it also adds the third (since the sum of the three roots is rational), and if it adds the third then it yields the splitting field, which is thus of degree 3. If a second extension adds the second root, then it also adds the third (since the sum ...), so you only ever need two extensions, one cubic and one quadratic, to get to the splitting field.

Answer (score 3):

At least one, and 'which' has no sense in this setting, as this root can be taken into any other root by a field automorphism of a (perhaps bigger) field over which f factors to linear components.

However, I think, in this generality this is not an easy question.

But 'a priori' only one root enters into the quotient $\Bbb Q[x]/(f)$. But! If the field operations yield other roots from this one, they also must be present. (I.e. in case of quadratic polynomial.)